# How to model an Entity that can have 1-M of multiple entities?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling, eloquent

Say there is an entity "Awards Ceremony." During an awards ceremony, a "Person" could get one "Award" (or another way of saying it: an award can be given to a person). This is simple enough to model.

However, it is also possible for a "Person" to be given multiple "Awards". Or an "Award" could be shared among multiple "Persons". This is where I am struggling with the modeling. I feel that I need at least 3 tables: Award Ceremony, Person, Award. Then I think I need a mapping table to correctly model how the Person entity might have multiple Award, or the Award might have multiple Person.

Any suggestions on how to model this?

I'm using MySQL. Also using Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

**EDIT 1:**

I think this is how it can be modeled:

```
award_ceremony
 - id
 - name

person
- id
- name

award
- id
- name

mapping
- id
- award_ceremony_id
- person_id
- award_id
```

It's the `mapping` table I'm not sure of.

Comment: Can same award be granted to same person multiple times (presumably on different ceremonies)?

Comment: The id in the mapping table is not required. This table's  PK is award_ceremony_id, person_id and award_id.  This combination is always unique. Eg.   2013 Nobel Prize, Physics, Peter Higgs  and 2013 Nobel Prize, Physics, Francios Englert. Introducing and extra  key field is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track.  All you need is an intersection table (many-to-many) table between the `Award` and the `Person` like so:

[image]

The `Recipient` table allows multiple people to share an award.  It also allows a person to win multiple awards.  Of course, it also allows awards to be won by just one person.

Note that `Recipient` doesn't need its own `id`, the primary key of `Recipient` would be the combination of the foreign keys to `Award` and `Person`.  Also, there is no reason to have a foreign key to `Award_Ceremony` since the relationship to `Award` already implies this relationship.

**Edit: Tables & Columns...**

You could use table/column definitions like so:

```
award_ceremony
 - id (PK)
 - name

person
- id (PK)
- name

award
- id (PK)
- name
- award_ceremony_id (FK)  // This belongs here!

recipient
- person_id (PK, FK)
- award_id (PK, FK)
```

Comment: Does my model fail, though? Is it not normalized?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - The potential issue with your model is that it has insert and delete anomalies.  Essentially, it has failed the test for fourth normal form.  Think of it this way: what does your model do to prevent someone recording that George RR Martin won best new rap album at the Oscars?  Also, how does your model represent that the Emmys has an award "outstanding variety series" prior to any winner(s) being announced?  The fact that a particular award goes with a particular ceremony is semantically independent of who wins the award.

Comment: Would your model work equally well if `award_ceremony_id (FK)` was put in the `person` table?

Comment: Putting award_ceremony_id (FK) in the person table would require multiple entries per person in the person table it they attended more than one ceremony.  If you want to represent attendance a better solution would be to have an intermediate table there as well.

Comment: The design of StackOverflowNewbie shows that an award could be assingned to a persion multiple times in a Ceremonys (Award entity is independent of Ceremony). The design of @JoelBrown shows that an award could be assingned to a persion in a Ceremony just once.

Comment: Just noting here that "award" would be "Best Rap" and "award_ceremony" would be "Oscars 2013". Then next year you could still win again.

Answer (score 0):

a person can have 1 or many award

person have award(s) || 1 to many relationship

```
person
- id (PK)
-award_id(PK,FK)
- name

award
- id (PK)
- name
```

//award ceremony can have many person

```
award_ceremony
-id (PK)
-person_id(FK)
-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added solution where you will have schema not fully normalized. I like one of the idea adding recipient entity as well but with modification. check both of this below.

**Solution:1**

```
    Ceremony
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)

    Person
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)

    Award
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)


    AwardOwner
        -AwardOwnerID
        -AwardID        =fk TO Award.ID
        -OwnerID        =fk TO Person.ID
        -CeremonyID     =fk TO Ceremony.ID
    PK = (AwardOwnerID)
    Unique = (AwardID+OwnerID+CeremonyID)
```

**Solution:2**

```
    Ceremony
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)

    Person
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)

    Award
        -ID
        -NAME
    PK = (ID)
    Unique= (Name)

    AwardCeremony
        -AwardCeremonyID
        -AwardID    =fk TO Award.ID
        -CeremonyID =fk TO Ceremony.ID
        PK = (AwardCeremonyID)
        Unique = (AwardID+CeremonyID)


    AwardCeremonyRecipient 
        -AwardCeremonyID    =fk TO AwardCeremony.AwardCeremonyID
        -Recipient ID       =fk TO Person.ID
        PK = (AwardCeremonyID+Recipient ID)
```